# Tracking information that is in constant flux

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Lately I have been looking around for free svn+trac repositories. Naturally, I came to SO and found a "question-answer thread" with multiple edits, as some of the providers changed their free repositories into charged ones (maybe v.v. and multiple times). Combined this development with the reputation system on SO, this can lead (or has lead) to a slight mess as some users post an answer of the new state, while others add edits to their old posts and so on.

Inspired by that use case, I wonder if it could be a good idea to introduce some kind of feature on SO that allows tracking information that is in flux. Maybe some special kind of question where an edit/update can yield reputation. This could lead to a very clean site with easy to sight/ordered information, further enhancing the use of SO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the right answer is a new feature. I think the right answer is making that kind of question Community Wiki, and editing the answers.  Duplicated answers should be deleted.

Comment: If such a question turned community wiki, it does not generate reputation any longer. I think reputation (maybe reduced in this kind of scenario) could do the trick in keeping the information accurate, as in effect humans jump in the role of web-services which are likely to never be provided.

Comment: Community Wiki doesn't address the User Experience problem. The SE UI is sort of clunky in the context of maintaining this kind of information, and neither the UI nor general user behavior lends itself well to the idea of "right answer" changing over time.